# Не получается передать переменную из функции, находясь в функции

Tags: javascript, phonegap

Проблема заключается в том, что я уже изначально нахожусь в функции:

```
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var iduserpush = 'no';
    alert('iduserpush =' + iduserpush);
    window.plugins.OneSignal.init(
            "*******************************",
            { googleProjectNumber: "*************" },
            app.notificationOpenedCallback
    );
    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
        window.iduserpush = ids.userId;
    });
    ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://test.ru/index.php?userpush=' + iduserpush,
            '_blank', 'location=no');
    window.open = ref;
}
```

Это часть кода. Изначально я нахожусь в `receivedEvent: function(id) {`.
Пытаюсь создать переменную `iduserpush`.
`alert` выводить переменную правильно, т.е. `iduserpush = no`.
Далее выполняется скрипт. Доходим до `window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {`.
Тут я пытаюсь поймать значение `ids.userId`.
Внутри функции всё хорошо, но далее я пытаюсь собрать `ref`, в котором упоминается `iduserpush`.
К сожалению, передается `no`.

Answer (score 1):

Функция, передаваемая в `window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds`, вызывается асинхронно, уже после того, как код с `ref = ...` выполнился.
Перенесите этот код внутрь функции:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
    iduserpush = ids.userId;
    ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://test.ru/index.php?userpush=' + iduserpush,
        '_blank', 'location=no');
    window.open = ref;
});
```

Также `window.iduserpush` я заменил на `iduserpush`, потому что это две разные переменные.